# libraries-override not working on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, theming

I'm trying to figure out how I can remove the default css libraries of Drupal 8 on the theme I'm working on. I tried using `libraries-override:` to remove a specific `CSS` but it doesn't seem to be working. The css file is still showing. As you can see the align.module.css is still showing on Google Network Tab. I'm not sure if the method I'm using is deprecated or incorrect

[image]

```
name: Barebones
description: Drupal light
type: theme
core: 8.x

base theme: stable

libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/modules/system/css/components/align.module.css: false
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe help(not tested)

**libraries-remove**

*The ability to remove entire libraries.*

libraries-remove:

1. subtheme/library
2. core/modernizr

**libraries-override**

*The ability to override entire libraries and parts of libraries:*

```yaml
libraries-override:
  # Replace an entire library.
  core/drupal.collapse: mytheme/collapse
  
  # Replace an asset with another.
  subtheme/library:
    css:
      theme:
        css/layout.css: css/my-layout.css
  
  # Remove an asset.
  drupal/dialog:
    css:
      theme:
        dialog.theme.css: false
  
  # Remove an entire library.
  core/modernizr: false
```

Comment: This is verbatim from the Change Record posted at https://www.drupal.org/node/2497313